# Error `Waiting for HGFS kernel module to load` during `vagrant up --provider=vmware_fusion`

Tags: vagrant, vmware-fusion, vmware-tools

Getting this error during `vagrant up --provider=vmware_fusion`:

`[default] Waiting for HGFS kernel module to load...
The HGFS kernel module was not found on the running virtual machine.
This must be installed for shared folders to work properly. Please
install the VMware tools within the guest and try again. Note that
the VMware tools installation will succeed even if HGFS fails
to properly install. Carefully read the output of the VMware tools
installation to verify the HGFS kernel modules were installed properly.`

Googling, I see that this is related to the problem

`$ lsmod | grep -i '^vmhgfs'
$`

but I'm not clear what the solution is.

I've installed VMWare tools in my base vmx that is being built by packer:

`$ vmware-
vmware-checkvm             vmware-uninstall-tools.pl
vmware-config-tools.pl     vmware-user
vmware-hgfsclient          vmware-vmblock-fuse
vmware-rpctool             vmware-xdg-detect-de
vmware-toolbox-cmd         vmware-xferlogs`

I also enabled Shared Folders in the VMWare settings

Any ideas what I can do?

- Some packer setting to enable HGFS?
- Something to change in the base vmx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answered by [@mitchellh on twitter](https://twitter.com/mitchellh/status/419560141298487296)

VMWare tools installation is silently failing during install because of missing gcc and linux headers.  I didn't see the error because I was running `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d` which doesn't stop on failure.

To fix the problem install prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Then reinstall VMWare tools (without the `-d` flag to make sure everything works properly)

```
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on jeff's answer,

The vmware tools image is found in `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/isoimages`

Unzip the iso file and you should find the vmware tools tar file inside. Get it inside the instance.

You will need to uninstall the existing vmware tools first. Run this

`sudo /usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl`

Then

`sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

And from the vmware tools package you extracted earlier, there should be a `vmware-install.pl` file. Run it

`sudo ./vmware-install.pl`

Reboot and your vmware tools should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Found an elegant solution [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4362#issuecomment-52684038), this needs to be added to the `Vagrantfile`:

```
# Ensure that VMWare Tools recompiles kernel modules when we update the linux images
$fix_vmware_tools_script = <<SCRIPT
sed -i.bak 's/answer AUTO_KMODS_ENABLED_ANSWER no/answer AUTO_KMODS_ENABLED_ANSWER yes/g' /etc/vmware-tools/locations
sed -i.bak 's/answer AUTO_KMODS_ENABLED no/answer AUTO_KMODS_ENABLED yes/g' /etc/vmware-tools/locations
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # ...
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $fix_vmware_tools_script
end
```